# Safari 100% DIV leaves space on right side

Tags: html, css, safari, width

I have a div that has a width of 100% and 10 divs at 10% inside. It works nicely in chrome but in Safari and Safari mobile on the iphone, it leaves space on the right side.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

```
<div style="width:100%;">
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#fff;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#000;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#fff;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#000;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#fff;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#000;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#fff;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#000;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#fff;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
   <div style="width:10%;background-color:#000;float:left;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your spaces (&nbsp), remove them and set a height on your divs and you'll notice it!